# How to execute function with parameter in PostgreSQL using anonymous code block in FireDAC?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, delphi, firedac

My database (PostgreSQL 11) has a function that must be called to execute an action. The return is not important, as long as there's no error. This function has arguments that must be passed as parameters.
I cannot directly use `TFDConnection.ExecSQL` because I use parameters of type array that is not supported by the method (to my knowledge). So, I use `TFDQuery.ExecSQL` like this:

```
msql1: = 'DO $$ BEGIN PERFORM DoIt (:id,:items); END $$; ';
    
{... create FDQuery (fq), set connection, set SQL.Text to msql1}
      
fq.Params.ParamByName ('id'). AsInteger: = 1;
    
{$ REGION 'items'}
fq.ParamByName ('items'). DataType: = ftArray;
fq.ParamByName ('items'). ArrayType: = atTable; // Must be atTable, not atArray
if length (items)> 0 then
begin
  fq.ParamByName ('items'). ArraySize: = length (items);
  for it: = 0 to length (items) -1 do
  fq.ParamByName ('items'). AsIntegers [it]: = items [it];
end;
fq.ExecSQL;
{$ ENDREGION}
```

When executing the above code, the error above message raises

> "Parameter 'id' not found".

After some research that suggested using `fq.Params.ParamByName` I was also unsuccessful.

However, if you change the way the function is called to
`select DoIt (:id,:items);` and obviously replacing the execution with `fq.Open` works perfectly.
Is it possible to execute a PL / pgSQL block that contains parameters in the function called by this block using TFDConnection / TFDQuery?

PS: I'm using Delphi Rio 10.3.3

Comment: Is `DoIt` a procedure or function? The title says function, but in your query you use `PERFORM`, which is dedicated for executing commands with no results (procedures).

Comment: For reasons of backward compatibility it is a function, but the result is not relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign a value to `TFDQuery.`SQL, FireDAC does some pre-processing of the SQL based on various options. `ResourceOptions.CreateParams` option controls whether parameters should be processed. This is enabled by default.

The preprocessor recognizes string literals in your SQL and doesn't try to look for the parameters in them. You used [dollar quoted string constant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) and that's why FireDAC doesn't recognize parameters in it. Even if you add parameter manually I think that FireDAC would not bind the value.

With that said, the proper way to execute stored procedures/function is to use [`TFDStoredProc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Executing_Stored_Procedures_(FireDAC)). You just assign `StoredProcName` and call its `Prepare` method which will retrieve procedure's metadata (parameters) from database so you don't need to set `ArrayType` or `DataType` of the parameter.

In your code you set the `DataType` to `ftArray` which is wrong, because in case of array parameter it should be set to array's element type. Anyway, by setting `fq.ParamByName ('items').AsIntegers` you effectively set parameter's `DataType` to `ftInteger`. All you need to do is to set `ArraySize`

Here's what you should do instead:

```
procedure DoIt(Connection: TFDConnection; ID: Integer; const Items: TArray<Integer>);
var
  StoredProc: TFDStoredProc;
  ParamItems: TFDParam;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  StoredProc := TFDStoredProc.Create(nil);
  try
    StoredProc.Connection := Connection;
    StoredProc.StoredProcName := 'DoIt';
    StoredProc.Prepare;
    StoredProc.Params.ParamByName('id').AsInteger := ID;
    if Length(Items) > 0 then
    begin
      ParamItems := StoredProc.Params.ParamByName('items');
      ParamItems.ArraySize := Length(Items);
      for Index := Low(Items) to High(Items) do
        ParamItems.AsIntegers[Index] := Items[Index];
    end;
    StoredProc.ExecProc;
  finally
    StoredProc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively you can use [`ExecFunc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomStoredProc.ExecFunc) to get the result of stored function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the main answer and for noticing an inappropriate (and painful) use of stored functions. I didn't know the use of TFDStoredProc. I was in doubt about two unanswered things (maybe a new question is needed): How to pass the default value of a function argument? What if the database (PostgreSQL) has two functions with the same name?

Comment: @AnselmoMS At the end of the first paragraph of [Executing Stored Procedures (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Executing_Stored_Procedures_(FireDAC)) you can find this note: *FireDAC does not support parameters with the default values*. That means you have to supply values for all parameters of the stored procedure.

Comment: Regarding overloaded procedures `TFDStoredProc` has [`Overload`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomStoredProc.Overload) property. Despite documentation says it's Oracle specific, I've noticed it is used in PG specific units. I'm not sure whether it works with PG, but I'd rather avoid overloaded procedures in database.

Comment: I understand. In another function I have a parameter that has the optional default value of the current date-time (from the database). But, to use TFDStoredProc, in this case, I would have to call the function that returns the current date-time, fill in the value of the parameter and send the value in the execution of the function, right?

Comment: Another way would be to overload the function and in one of them, the date-time parameter does not exist. But for that I would have to control which version of the function in the database would be prepared. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @AnselmoMS As I already indicated, overloaded DB functions are pain to deal with and it gets even worse when trying to call them from FireDAC. I'd recommend you to use unique function names like `MyFunc(IN Date DATE)` and `MyFuncWithDefaultDate()`.